# growth condition for Zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

How can I prove that
$$
-\frac{\zeta'(z)}{\zeta(z)}-\frac{1}{z-1}=O(|z|^{M})\quad\text{for }\Re(z)\geq1
$$
for $M$ constant large enough? $\zeta(s)$ is Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Context? What do you already know about $\zeta(s)$?

Comment: I know the series expansion for $\zeta'(s)$, that $\zeta(s)\neq0$ per $\Re(s\geq0)$ and that $\zeta$ can be holomorphically extended to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$

Comment: A $\log^A |s|$  bound appears when proving that $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros on $\Re(s)=1$.